# What is the format and meaning of the output of apt list?

Tags: apt

I am comparing the packages installed on 2 different servers using `apt list --installed`.

On one I see this:

```
adduser/bionic,now 3.116ubuntu1 all [installed]
```

And the other has:

```
adduser/bionic,bionic,now 3.116ubuntu1 all [installed]
```

So why the extra `bionic`?  Also, what does the `now` mean?  Is bionic the original version and now it is at version 3.116?

Comment: Good question - I tried to figure it out from the source code, but gave up when I came to the comment `// FIXME: some of these names are really icky – and all is nowhere documented` ;)

Comment: [`man apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html) doesn't break it down. It says it's similar to `dpkg-query --list`, but it has a different output format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comma-separated list following the package name after a slash seems to be the names of all suites containing the displayed (installed or candidate) version of the package. The suites from Ubuntu's default repositories are normally `VERSION`, `VERSION-updates`, `VERSION-security`, `VERSION-backports` and `VERSION-proposed`, where VERSION is your Ubuntu release codename, e.g. `xenial` for 16.04 or `bionic` for 18.04.

Multiple mentions of the same suite seem to indicate that multiple architectures of the same package version are available from that suite (usually 32/64 bit). About your two different machines, could it be that one is 32 bit only and one is 64 bit with 32 bit multi-arch support?

`now` apparently indicates that you have a local, cached version of the package, corresponding to a line with `/var/lib/dpkg/status` in the output of `apt policy`. It is present on all installed packages too.

Example with some random packages:

```
$ apt list zenity zenity-common zziplib-bin
Listing... Done
zenity/xenial,now 3.18.1.1-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
zenity-common/xenial,xenial,now 3.18.1.1-1ubuntu2 all [installed,automatic]
zziplib-bin/xenial-updates,xenial-security 0.13.62-3ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64

$ apt policy zenity zenity-common zziplib-bin
zenity:
  Installed: 3.18.1.1-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.18.1.1-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.18.1.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
zenity-common:
  Installed: 3.18.1.1-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.18.1.1-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.18.1.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
zziplib-bin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.13.62-3ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
     0.13.62-3ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
     0.13.62-3 500
        500 http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: ... I wondered if the multiples might be foreign architectures, but didn't want to break my system testing that

Comment: Hmm...`uname -a` is returning the same output for both servers...both are virtual machines on the same physical machine.

Comment: Compare `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` of both machines maybe?

Comment: Bingo!  `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` returns `i386` on the server with the extra `bionic` and the other one does not return anything.  Now to dig into what foreign-architectures are...

Comment: As I said, it's about multi-arch support. Adding a foreign architecture in dpkg allows you to install packages for that architecture, even though it is not your default/main architecture. Most commonly you see this on 64 bit systems ("amd64" as main architecture) which have support for 32 bit packages ("i386" as foreign architecture) enabled. Of course your CPU must still be compatible with that architecture, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: I am now wondering if the *order* of the comma-separated items after the package name has any significance.  On one I see `apparmor/bionic-security,bionic-updates`  and the other has `apparmor/bionic-updates,bionic-security`.  Maybe I'm just not using the best method of comparing what is installed on one versus the other...

Comment: I don't know for sure, but the ordering of those is probably arbitrary. After all, both suites provide the exactly same package version.

Comment: Haha...just realized the following has been telling me all along I shouldn't have been expecting apt to produce consistent output: `WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.`

Comment: @ByteCommander, `Multiple mentions of the same suite seem to indicate that multiple architectures of the same package version are available from that suite (usually 32/64 bit). About your two different machines, could it be that one is 32 bit only and one is 64 bit with 32 bit multi-arch support?`  why should apt care for current machine - it's should care for whats in the repo and report it... and it should be independent of on what machine the `apt` command is executed on. ??

Comment: @samshers Look at the example for `zenity-common`, one entry mentions `amd64`, one `i386`. What apt lists depends on what software is available for it to download, which depends on the configured repositories and your machine's (primary and additional compatible) architectures. A repo can host packages for many architectures, but apt will only care about those that it thinks will work for your system, as shown by `dpkg --print-architecture ; dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`